# The Custom Property of My Custom Open Graph Object is Not Shown in the Share Dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I cannot get the custom properties of my custom Open Graph object displayed in the Share dialog of my Android app. I created a custom object **channel** in the namespace **myradio_android**, and defined a custom property **current_song_title** in channel. I also created a custom action **enjoy**, but I cannot get the my custom property current_song_title displayed in the Share dialog. What I get can be seen the pasted image below.

Here's the code I am using to create the Share dialog:

```
    // Facebook
    mImageButtonShareOnFacebook = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.shareOnFacebook);
    mImageButtonShareOnFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(_albumCover)
                    .setUserGenerated(true)
                    .build();

            // Create an object
            ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                    .putString("og:type", "myradio_android:channel")
                    .putString("og:title", channel.getName())
                    .putString("og:description", "My description")
                    .putString("myradio_android:channel:current_song_title", _title)
                    .putPhoto("og:image", photo)
                    .build();


            // Create an action
            ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                    .setActionType("myradio_android:enjoy")
                    .putObject("channel", object)

                    .build();

            // Create the content
            ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                    .setPreviewPropertyName("channel")
                    .setAction(action)
                    .build();

            ShareDialog.show(NowPlayingFragment.this, content);

        }
    });
```

[image]

Edit: I have attached the Edit Attachments dialog:

[image]

Comment: Did you configure your story to show custom object properties? See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom#configure, Attachments->Item Layout. To use any of your custom properties in one of the caption lines, start typing a `{`, then an autocomplete list of all available properties should show up.

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that (see the attached screenshot) It is still not showing up.

Comment: Does it show up in the final post that is made then?

Comment: No, unfortunately not... Somehow, the description is displayed although I did put it in the layout... What am I missing?

Comment: Hasn't anybody faced a similar problem?

Comment: Does this work the way you want once you share the post? if so, then this is likely by design and not a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `myradio_android:channel:current_song_title` try `myradio_android:current_song_title`