# No Preview When Publishing a Open Graph Common Action (Listen) to Facebook from an Android App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

After a failed attempt to create my custom story in Facebook (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020536/the-custom-property-of-my-custom-open-graph-object-is-not-shown-in-the-share-dia))

I decided to use the "Listen" Open Graph common action pre-defined by Facebook. Here's my code:

```
    // Facebook
    mImageButtonShareOnFacebook = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.shareOnFacebook);
    mImageButtonShareOnFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(_albumCover)
                    .setUserGenerated(true)
                    .build();

            // Create an object
            String fbAppId = getActivity().getString(R.string.facebook_app_id);
            ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                    .putString("fb:app_id", fbAppId)
                    .putString("og:type", "music.song")
                    .putString("og:title", _title + " by " + _artist + " in XYZ Radio " + channel.getName() + " channel")
                    .putString("og:site_name", "XYZ Radio")
                    .putPhoto("og:image", photo)
                    .build();

            // Create an action
            ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                    .setActionType("music.listens")
                    .putObject("song", object)

                    .build();

            // Create the content
            ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                    .setPreviewPropertyName("song")
                    .setAction(action)
                    .build();


            ShareDialog.show(NowPlayingFragment.this, content);

        }
    });
```

And here's what I am getting:

[image]

The published post seems be correct, though.

[image]

So, why am I getting that "A preview will be added after you post this link to..." message? Is that the default behaviour or what am I missing? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is by design, read more about [pre-caching here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching):

> When content is shared for the first time, the Facebook crawler will
> scrape and cache the metadata from the URL shared. The crawler has to
> see an image at least once before it can be rendered. This means that
> the first person who shares a piece of content won't see a rendered
> image.

I believe a similar concept applies for OG previews.

Comment: Yes, I found that out, also. Thank you.